# How do I instrument additional functions in X-Ray with AWS Lambda function in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I am trying to instrument an AWS Lambda function using X Ray. According to the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray-sdk-for-python/latest/reference/basic.html) of the `aws_xray_sdk`, I can't instrument anything outside the handler function. If I have the following sample code:

```
from aws_xray_sdk.core import xray_recorder


@xray_recorder.capture("handler")
def my_handler(event, context):
  # some code here
  xray_recorder.begin_subsegment("my_function")
  my_function(params)
  xray_recorder.end_subsegment("my_function")
  return {"message": "done"}

@xray_recorder.capture("my_function")
def my_function(params):
  # do work
```

nothing gets instrumented in X-Ray traces other than `handler`. I have tried with different combinations of `begin_subsegment` and not having `@xray_recorder.capture()` on `my_function`. Nothing seems to generate any traces for `my_function`. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to change

```
xray_recorder.end_subsegment("my_function")
```

to

```
xray_recorder.end_subsegment()
```

Comment: Also note per the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray-sdk-for-python/latest/reference/basic.html#manually-create-segment-subsegment): "The `xray_recorder` keeps one segment per thread. Therefore, in manual mode, call `xray_recorder.end_segment()` before creating a new segment, otherwise the new segment overwrites the existing one"